# wine error when using divfix

Tags: scientific-linux, wine

When I'm logged in through SSH to a Scientific Linux 6.3 machine I get this error message:

```
/usr/bin/wine /home/USER/.divfix/DivFix++.exe -i INPUT.avi -o out.avi
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/test/.wine'
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

I have set the DISPLAY variable..:

```
grep -i display ~/.bashrc 
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
```

I have X/GUI:

```
yum groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
```

I have "yum update" and then rebooted (so up-to-date). What am I missing? please help.

UPDATE:

```
xset -q
No protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't have a X server running on that machine: Wine requires one even for command-line-only software.

Since DivFix++ is a command-line-only application, install Xvfb (`xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` package I think; search `xvfb` on yum):

> Xvfb or X virtual framebuffer is an X11 server that performs all graphical operations in memory, not showing any screen output.

Then launch a dummy X server using `Xvfb :1 &`, after this `export DISPLAY=:1 ; /usr/bin/wine /home/USER/.divfix/DivFix++.exe -i INPUT.avi -o out.avi`.

It should be enough to keep Wine happy.

Comment: I started "Xvfb :1 &" as root, then as the "USER" I "export DISPLAY=:1 ;" and then I launched divfix, this is what I got: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1222240/ - the out.avi didn't got created

Comment: and I used: yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.x86_64

Comment: IT FIXED!! :) I just had to try out the 32bit version of the divfix... because I used the 64bit version, but I will write your solution down, in case it's needed in another places